# why the for loop cannot define two scope's variables?

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope

I am confusing with the "**'iter' was not declared in this scope**" error.

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for(std::size_t i,vector<int>::iterator iter=vec.begin();iter!=vec.end();++i,++iter)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Because syntax is defined that way

Comment: at the begining ,i thought it may cause by scope ,now i understanded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just like you can do

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
```

A for loop's first section does the same thing.  Since you can't do

```
int a = 10, double b = 20;
```

The same thing applies to the for loop.

Technically you can have two different types as you can declare an type and a pointer to that same type on the same line like

```
int i = 0, *b = nullptr;
```

And that is also valid to do in a for loop.

Comment: yes,i understand.thank you

Answer (score 6):

In C++17, there is a feature known as a [structured binding declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type) that allows you do to do this. For example:

```
for (auto [iter, i] = std::tuple{vec.begin(), 0u}; iter != vec.end(); ++iter, ++i) 
{
    /* ... */
}
```

While this nearly matches the syntax you were hoping for, the `tuple` part is not very readable, so I would just declare one of the variables outside of the loop.

[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OiHEqSlJPYiNoOfy)

Answer (score 5):

It can, but both variables need to be the same type.

The common thing to do, when you need to maintain an index as well as an iterator is to write

```
{ // extra scoping block
    std::size_t i = 0; // indeed, you need to initialise i
    for(vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++i,++iter)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,i just don't know why?

Comment: ..I saw that ..

Comment: @LiKui Because it's the syntax of the language.

Comment: This is quite ugly, but admittedly there is no better way. I use this too quite often.